# How to read the records in user table?

Tags: postgresql, psql

Recently, I want to use psql command line to remove records in user table, but I couldn't get the records inside by using the following command before I delete any of them:

```
postgres=> select * from user;

But the system returns the DB owner only.
```

So I am wondering, is the table contents are hidden.

Answer (score 0):

The command used above is checking the database system's internal users. If you want to check client's external users, need to put a ***double quote on the table name***.

```
postgres=> select * from "user";
```

Then the table data would be shown .

Comment: A perfect example of why you should not user [reserved words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-keywords-appendix.html) as an object name, in this case a table. You have no idea exactly when Postgres will allow usage as the object and when it will impose a predefined meaning. Note also that although Postgres may allow non-standard use since it is reserved the developers are within their rights changing that at any time. Safest option DO NOT USE RESERVED WORDS AS OBJECT NAMES.